# Can iText 7 extract table data from a PDF file?

Tags: java, itext

## **May I ask a question, whether iText 7 can extract table data from a PDF file?**

Currently, I am learning to use iText 7, which is a great open-source software that I really like. However, I have encountered a problem while learning. May I ask how to extract data from a table in a PDF file, and ensure the data is valid? Moreover, if there are multiple tables on the same page of the PDF file, how can I extract the data from each of the tables separately?

Looking forward to your reply, thank you.

Comment: As @KJ says, what we see as tables in pdf, often internally merely are some lines and text pieces. Thus, often one needs sophisticated guesswork to identify tables. Such guesswork is usually only implemented in dedicated projects (like tabula), not in the general purpose pdf libraries (like iText). If the pdf is properly tagged, though, table extraction with iText is possible using those tags. So: Are your pdfs properly tagged? Furthermore, what do you mean by *"ensure the data is valid"*? By which criteria should iText validate the data?

Comment: doing that is not an easy task, that's why we've created [pdf2Data](https://itextpdf.com/products/pdf2data/extract-your-content-from-pdf), which leverages on iText 7, and in the near future, iText 8.